# Take $S$ to be a set of ordinals, show $\cup S=\sup(S)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, supremum-and-infimum

Ok so firstly I can see how this makes sense. If you have say: 
$S=\{0,1,2\}$ with $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}, 2 = \{0,1\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$.

$$\cup S = \{\emptyset,\emptyset,\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\} = \{0,1\} = 2$$

(I think this is right?)

Now I suppose I could prove it by induction but I was told of another proof where you show:

$\sup(S) \subseteq \cup S$ and then $\cup S \subseteq \sup(S) $ (Can someone explain how to write out this proof? I see how if you do both sides you are basically showing $\sup(S) = \cup S$)

Thanks!

Comment: Hint, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two ordinals, then $\alpha<\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\subset \beta$ is a proper inclusion.

Comment: Hi so using what you said if I then go: Firstly if $\cup S \supseteq Sup(S)$: $\alpha \in \cup S$, and as $\alpha \lt \beta$ for some $\beta \in S$ then $\alpha \in \beta$ and so $\beta \leq Sup(S)$ meaning $\alpha \in Sup(S)$ then for $Sup(S) \supseteq \cup S$: $\alpha \in Sup(S)$ so $\alpha \leq Sup(S)$, so there must be a $\beta \in S$ such that $\alpha \in \beta$, so $\alpha \in \cup S$ ?? (Does that look good / sufficient enough proof?) Thanks.

Comment: You say "as $\alpha<\beta$ for some $\beta\in S$, but this isn't necessarily true, for if $S=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, then $\bigcup{S}=\{\emptyset\}$, and there is no element of $S$ greater than $\{\emptyset\}$.  Have you shown that if $S$ is a set of ordinals, then $\bigcup{S}$ is an ordinal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\alpha\leq\beta$ if and only if $\alpha\subseteq\beta$ (either $\alpha\in\beta$, and it follows from transitivity, or $\alpha=\beta$).

Now if $\alpha\in S$ then $\alpha\subseteq\bigcup S$, so $\bigcup S\geq\alpha$ and therefore $\bigcup S\geq\sup S$.

On the other hand, if $\alpha<\bigcup S$ then there is some $\beta\in S$ and $\gamma\in\beta$ such that $\alpha<\gamma$. In particular $\alpha\subseteq\gamma\subseteq\beta$, so $\alpha<\sup S$. therefore $\bigcup S\leq\sup S$.

And equality follows.